# Space between minipages

Tags: minipage

On my Ruby book, I break the code listing if it don' fit on the page using minipages. But the page before the minipage, if there is some space remaining, distribute it on an uniform way between the page.

Is there any option to say "hey, keep the text on the page top size", making it create a bigger empty space on the bottom?

I'd love to remove spaces between 16.4 and 16.5 and keep it on the bottom. On page 420 we have a minipage and other on page 421 that is the reason the page broke, because it don't fit on page 420.

Thanks!

Edit: the code to create this specific section is as below:

```
\section{Executando tarefas em outros programas}

Podemos executar as tarefas em outros programas, como no {\tt irb}:

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Ruby]
$ irb
require "rake"
=> true

load "Rakefile"
=> true

Rake::Task["files:list"].invoke
encontrei o arquivo: 1.txt
encontrei o arquivo: 2.txt
encontrei o arquivo: 3.txt
=> [#<Proc:0x000000021b50d8@Rakefile:10>]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

Reparem que no final é retornada uma {\tt Proc}.

\section{Arquivos diferentes}

Até agora estamos executando todas as tarefas em um arquivo {\tt Rakefile},
porém podemos ter vários arquivos {\tt .rake} com código especificos, indicados
na linha de comando, como por exemplo, {\tt dependent.rake}:

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\lstinputlisting[language=Ruby, caption=Arquivo Rake com nome fora do padrão]{./code/rake/dependent.rake}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

What I'm trying to do:

[image]

Comment: Without knowing your code, I guess you could use `\newpage` or `\clearpage` between the minipages. But maybe there would be a better suggestion, if you'd show us a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), that can be used to reproduce your problem. Even not using `minipage` could in some cases be an idea. `\raggedbottom` is mostly not the best idea for books. But who knows …

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: minipage has no spacing code, it is just positioned like a large letter. So any space between them is due to your page layout code, paragraph spacing and other details you have not shown.

Comment: You can add \vfill to the bottom of a page to shrink any glue above, then use \raisebox to overlap the gap.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the answers! I edited my original question to provide the code I'm using. There are 2 `minipages` there, both using `lstlisting`. I also uploaded an image of what I'm trying to do.

Tags like `\newpage` and `\clearpage` would fit perfectly, but I was trying to find a way to don't need to check all the page breaks and keep LaTeX breaking it for me.

Comment: Please follow the link in my comment. Why are you using `minipage`? Usually not using a `minipage` but either allow page breaks inside the listing or use floating listings would avoid the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the [`needspace` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/needspace). To make it fully automatic you will need to do some work to measure the minipages, similar to how it was done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/582282/119). // If this happens a lot, maybe just using `\raggedbottom` would be simpler though.